# What is a perl script

Tags: shell-script, perl

I'm wondering if someone can explain to me what a perl script is, and when we would use them vs when we would use a bash script.

I've googled it multiple times but I can't seem to get an answer that I understand. Can someone explain it in very simple terms, as I am very new at linux?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "script" is often a text file containing commands written in a particular scripting language, or more generally, instructions for some scriptable interpreter. Unix systems support scripts written in a multitude of scripting languages, and Perl is one of these.  Others include `bash`, `sh`, `awk`, `sed`, Python, Ruby etc.

The Perl language is well described in Perl programming books and many online tutorials, guides etc. that should be easily found via a simple web search.

Scripting languages other than the various shell languages are often used when the shells' capabilities are not enough to conveniently solve the issue at hand.  This could be due to the shells' lack of efficiency, a lack in terse syntax for doing certain things, or the simple inability to express certain programming constructs or data structures, at least in a simple way.  Non-shell languages, such as Perl, also provide a wealth of libraries for doing many tasks that would be inefficient, insecure (or difficult to do securely), or near impossible to do at all in a shell script.

General inquiries about how to *write* Perl scripts is more a topic for [the StackOverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/) (see also their help pages about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)).

Answer (score 1):

A bash (or shell) script is mostly "glue" between system commands that do most of the processing, there is relatively little logic in the script itself.

A Perl script is a program written for the Perl interpreter, that can combine system commands (like a shell script) with some heavy processing of their output, one of Perl's strengths being the processing of text.

Answer (score 0):

A **bash** script means that it uses the *bash* interpreter; **perl** is the same thing. Try https://www.perl.org/.

Comment: "_it uses the `bash`interpreter_" ... to do what? "_`perl` is the same thing_" ... if `perl` is the same as `bash` why would i need both? You might want to expand on your answer a little.